# Remove a -webkit-transform from an element via JavaScript

Tags: javascript, css, transform

I am trying to work around this bug: http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=20574 thinking of performing the transform, and then afterwards removing it while positioning the element in its end position via JavaScript.

I tried

```
document.getElementById('popover').style.setProperty("-webkit-transform", "translate3d(0,0,0)")
```

and

```
document.getElementById('popover').style.setProperty("-webkit-transform", "none")
```

None seem to have any effect.

If I remove the transforms and position the elements manually the fixed element does behave as it should.

Here are the transforms themselves:

```
#popover.open {
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    -webkit-animation: openpopup 0.2s 1;
    -webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
} 
#popover.closed {
    -webkit-animation: closepopup 0.2s 1;
    -webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
} 
@-webkit-keyframes openpopup {
    from {
        -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 100%, 0);
    }
    to {
        -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0%, 0);
    }
}
@-webkit-keyframes closepopup {
    from {
        -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0%, 0);
    }
    to {
        -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 100%, 0);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Javascript had a different name for the css property you are trying to change. It's called `WebkitTransform`.

`document.getElementById('popover').style.setProperty("WebkitTransform", "none");` Should work.

Comment: That didn't seem to have an effect. Returns 'undefined' when I run it, and nothing else appears to change. I would expect the element to return to where it would be before the transform?

Comment: For the record, you could as well have done this: `document.getElementById('popover').style.WebkitTransform = "none";`. Speaking of which, you can get those properties by inspecting `document.getElementById('popover').style` in your browser console (of course don't expect `WebkitTransform` to show up in Firefox's console).

Comment: that's weird.. it's tranform property is blank after the transform, but fixed elements are still fixed to the top of the transformed div instead of the window. I guess it goes deeper.